# List the maximum or minimum of the elements at each position of two arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

Given two `Fixnum` arrays of equal length, is there a Ruby way to produce an array holding the maximum or minimum values at each index?

For example:

```
a1 = [ 10, 30 ]
a2 = [ 5,  35 ]
```

The `min` function would return `5` from the first column and `30` from the second column, giving `[5, 30]`. Likewise, the `max` function would return `10` from the first column and `35` from the second column, giving `[10, 35]`.

Comment: would the min and max functions have to be the same size?

Comment: Is it possible to have more than two arrays being compared? Could the arrays have more than two elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[a1, a2].transpose.map &:minmax
```

Given a larger pair of arrays, it stores the minmax at each index.

```
a1 = [ 10, 30, 8, 15 ]
a2 = [ 17, 23, 5,  35 ]

p [a1, a2].transpose.map &:minmax   #  => [[10, 17], [23, 30], [5, 8], [15, 35]]
```

Borodin's answer is faster.

Answer (score 7):

You can construct arrays of the elements at common positions (that is, [transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) a row-wise 2D array into a column-wise 2D array), then map the min or max (or whatever else) values out of each column:

```
[a1, a2].transpose.map &:min    #  => [5, 30]
[a1, a2].transpose.map &:max    #  => [10, 35]
```

Comment: Ah, now I see what he was trying to do. Good answer.

Comment: Or use the [`minmax`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax) method which returns them both at once.

Comment: @theTinMan: That would be the same as transposing and then sorting each pair.

Comment: `[a1, a2].transpose` is identical to `a1.zip(a2)`, which is probably faster.

Comment: Transpose is (very slightly) faster, according to benchmarks on 1 million iterations of zip and transpose on Ruby 2.0.0.  But I think I prefer the `zip` version for readability.

Comment: Cool! This is exactly my script needs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just swap each pair if the largest is first:

```
a1 = [ 10, 30 ]
a2 = [ 5,  35 ]

minmax = a1.zip(a2).map { |pair| pair.sort }

p minmax
```

**output**

```
[[5, 30], [10, 35]]
```